# In mongodb,How to use aggregation to get the correspondence between fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an example collection of documents:

```
{name:"Danny", age:20, gender: 0}
{name:"Jordan", age:15, gender: 1}
{name:"Li Mei", age:20, gender: 1}
{name:"Soojin", age:17, gender: 0}
{name:"Zhang Ming", age:22, gender: 1}
```

I want to get the following results by grouping according to gender

```
{
  "Test field":[{name:"Danny", age: 20}, {name:"Soojin", age: 17}]
}
{
  "Test field":[{name:"Jordan", age: 15}, {name:"Li Mei", age: 20}, {name: "Zhang Ming", age: 22}]
}
```

What query can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$gender",
      "Test Field": {
        "$push": {
          age: "$age",
          name: "$name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

See it working [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8BOF34p4vri).

Comment: wow!He is feasible!Thank you very much for your help,I will always remember it